# Are there btc in this multibit wallet

Tags: wallet, multibit

I have several multibit wallets I put in storage years ago, and I'd like to check if there's btc in them . I see wallet IDs for 'receive address'  in the .info files - if those show 0btc does this mean the wallet is empty? Or is the receive addr not where btc would be stored?
I'd like to verify there's actually something in there before banging my head against how to retrieve from what looks like an unsupported wallet type.

The dirs look like:

```
wallet1.info
wallet1.wallet
wallet1-data
    key-backup
    wallet-backup
    rolling-backup
    wallet-unenc-backup
```

and the .info files look like (for wallet1 in this case):

```
multiBit.info,1
walletVersion,3
receive,1GFM...RGdp,
property,walletDescription,wallet1
property,walletBackupFile,C%3A%5CUsers%5Cjeremy%5CDocuments%5C%5Cwallet1-data%5Crolling-backup%5Cwallet1-20131201123906.wallet
property,receiveAddress,1GFM...RGdp
property,receiveLabel,
```

Comment: Is your wallet encrypted? If not the wallet file is plain text, if yes you'll have decrypt it first.

Comment: There is a receive address in the (unencrypted) wallet1.info  - my question was whether this revc address  ( whose balance can be checked on a blockchain explorer) necessarily reflects the wallet contents.

Answer (score 1):

First dump your keys using the instructions [here](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/read-multibit-wallet-file#installation)

Then open a new Electrum wallet, ask it to "Import private keys", and paste your private keys there.

Then you will be able to spend from there if you have coins.

Comment: thanks - tho I was actually after whether I can determine wallet contents/address before actually extracting, by use of the plaintext receive addr. in the .info file

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Multibit's wallet format, so I don't know a shortcut.

Comment: I added the .info file contents, my question is basically whether that receive wallet addr necessarily reflects the wallet contents